# Subclassing window in DLL causes crash at DLL unload

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, subclassing

I have a DLL that loads dynamically during program work (specifically: a DLL-plugin for [mIRC](http://www.mirc.com/)). After DLL is loaded I subclass program's window and an editbox in it to catch some messages:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ChatWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}


LRESULT CALLBACK EditBoxProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData) {
    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

...

//wndMirc and channelEditBox acquired elsewhere
SetWindowSubclass(channelEditBox, EditBoxProc, EditBoxProcId, nullptr);
SetWindowSubclass(wndMirc, ChatWndProc, ChannelWndProcId, nullptr);
```

At DLL unloading I remove subclasses:

```
RemoveWindowSubclass(wndMirc, ChatWndProc, ChannelWndProcId);
RemoveWindowSubclass(channelEditBox, EditBoxProc, EditBoxProcId);
```

After that, the program crashes altogether with nothing but exception visible only to debugger `Exception thrown at 0x0FAA3559 in mIRC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x0FAA3559.`

However, if I *don't* subclass the window, only the editbox, everything is fine (except that I can't intercept window's messages). In both cases `GetLastError` doesn't indicate any problems.

I've read that subclassing windows which your program doesn't own isn't exactly bright idea, but with hooks I get much uglier code + I couldn't intercept some messages (like WM_KEYDOWN in editbox). Any help appreciated.

**Edit:** to clarify things, unloading happens in two phases: at first from mIRC internals `int __stdcall UnloadDll(int isTimeout)` is called, where I remove my subclasses; then `BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hDllHandle, DWORD dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)` is called with `dwReason==DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` - after the second phase, the program crashes.

**Edit 2:** Stack trace at crashsite:

```
0f7e3559()  Unknown
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing]  
comctl32.dll!71f1f5ee() Unknown
user32.dll!752871be()   Unknown
user32.dll!75286238()   Unknown
user32.dll!752868ea()   Unknown
user32.dll!752878b0()   Unknown
user32.dll!75287d31()   Unknown
user32.dll!75287dfa()   Unknown
mIRC.exe!01107f9f() Unknown
mIRC.exe!0110e0e9() Unknown
mIRC.exe!011eec7c() Unknown
kernel32.dll!759d33aa() Unknown
ntdll.dll!77049f72()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!77049f45()    Unknown
```

Comment: _"At DLL unloading"_ do you mean DLL_PROCESS_DETACH?  If so many parts of the OS are "electrified" as they have already shut down.  Have a read of https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170203-00/?p=95345  to get a general idea of the issues.  Simply put doing almost anything in `DllMain` is a really bad idea.

Comment: It is risky.  Trouble starts when the window is sub-classed more than once, it needs to be unsubclassed in the right order.  And "at DLL unloading" is a pretty major red flag, don't do this in DllMain().  WM_NCCLOSE is a good trigger.  And post a stack trace, you leave entirely too much guessing.

Comment: @RichardCritten in `DllMain` I only store `hInstance` for later use at `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a way to understand if I unsubclass things in the right order?

Comment: are your DLL unloading **always at same thread** that it was loading ? you check this ? this is always will be true ?

Comment: at first you need install pdb symbols, for view names in callstack. `location 0x0FAA3559` - this is what ? this is not `ChatWndProc` ? at which address was loaded you dll ?

Comment: ["One gotcha that isn't explained clearly in the documentation is that you must remove your window subclass before the window being subclassed is destroyed."](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031111-00/?p=41883)

Comment: faster of all call `RemoveWindowSubclass` fail. and windows continue call your `ChatWndProc`. you stack not enough informative without symbols, but look like this `comctl32.MasterSubclassProc` try call your `ChatWndProc` (at `0x0FAA3559`) but dll is already unloaded.

Comment: The stack trace isn't very helpful. See [Debugging with Symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588.aspx) to change that.